# Cakephp how to set checkbox value selected?

Tags: cakephp-2.0

I am using checkbox in one of my project.I am giving checkbox code below:

```
$this->Form->checkbox('ClubOpenDay.status', array("data-on-label" => "Open", "data-off-label" => "Close", "checked" => "checked"), array("empty" => false))
```

Here,Open is active by default. But in edit mode,if value is set to close,than close will be display.I am unable to do that.I just want,if I get value open from database,it will display open else close by default.Any idea about it?

Answer (score 0):

Well you should get the value from the database as you say and in the view just have an if statement, should look something like this:

```
if($value == true){
    $this->Form->checkbox('ClubOpenDay.status', array("data-on-label" => "Open", "data-off-label" => "Close", "checked" => "checked"), array("empty" => false))
}
else{
    $this->Form->checkbox('ClubOpenDay.status', array("data-on-label" => "Open", "data-off-label" => "Close"), array("empty" => false))
}
```

$value should be a variable that you assing from your controller that has the value true if its open or false if its closed, or maybe not even true or false, a 1 or 0 would do you would only need to change the if statement in your view accordingly

I hope that helps, good luck

Answer (score 0):

You can save your if else time

```
$checked = ($status == true) ? 'checked' : '';

$this->Form->checkbox('ClubOpenDay.status', array("data-on-label" => "Open", "data-off-   label" => "Close", "checked" => $checked), array("empty" => false))
```

Answer (score 0):

In your Controller you have to write this

```
public function edit($id){ // for example
    //[...]
    $this->request->data['ClubOpenDay']['status'] = $db_value;
    //$this->request->data['ClubOpenDay']['status'] = 1; // if you want to force a checkbox checked
}
```

And your checkbox will be automatically checked or unchecked.